# How do I reverse a Google App Engine update

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am moving off google appengine but still have apps in python2.7.
I just did a gcloud components update without checking what would happen.

I now get the Error: python 2 is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK.  Please use python version 3.5 and up.

I have a large application that is at end of life so I just need to be able to modify it to extract data.
Questions:
Is there any wat to revers the gcloud components update or update to an older version that supports python 2.7
Or, is there another way to extract data from Google Datastore into .csv files?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To reverse it, you install a specific version using the command

   `gcloud components update --version <VERSION_NO>`

   or you can download a specific version using the format [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives)
2. `dev_appserver.py` still supports Python 2.7 apps. What happened is that starting from version [427.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#breaking_changes_5), gcloud CLI (i.e. `dev_appserver.py`) now needs to be invoked with Python 3.5+

   So if you want to go to a version that requires running `dev_appserver.py` using Python 2, you should install version `426.0.0`.

   You can also have 2 versions installed on your machine and use them separately depending on your needs. See [this](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-gcloud-sdk-cli-on-the-same-machine/) blog article from us on how to do that.
3. Out of the box, gcloud SDK/CLI doesn't support exporting your datastore to CSV but if you do a search on Google, you might find 3rd party apps that support it. e.g. our [App](https://nocommandline.com/) allows exporting data to CSV/JSON and importing from them

Comment: Thanks NoCommandLine, much appreciated.  I can code for the .csv extracts, I was just hopeful.